# Seeking suggestions regarding JIRA customizations for a "Periodic Tasks" project

Tags: jira

I am tasked with establishing a JIRA project for "Periodic Tasks" like software license and SSL certificate renewals, manual review of logs, annual year-end database processes, re-authorization of external users, etc.

I am sure our organization is not the first to use JIRA for this purpose. I am interested in corresponding with others who have gone down this road. I would like to see what custom fields, screens, workflows, etc. have proved useful.

I have created a new project, set the key, description, project lead... and created a new Periodic Tasks Issue Type Scheme with just issue types "task" and "sub-task".  I also created a Periodic Tasks Notification Scheme; right now it is an exact copy of our default notification scheme, but it seems likely that they will diverge.  My permission scheme and issue security scheme are default, but, I can easily imagine some environments where these periodic tasks might require different security (in our case the developers and operations people work pretty close -- in fact sometimes we are the same person.)

Right now I am using the default workflow, but, I expect to change that as soon as I get enough experience to confidently understand the requirements.

But when I come to Components, I am of two minds.  One approach would be to try to organize this by our components.  Perhaps categories of components: servers, certificates, software licenses....  Another approach is to use Components to categorize by type of task: license renewal, certificate renewal, year-end process....  I have implemented as the type of task because I think that this will be a smaller and more stable list of categories.

I am particularly interested in seeing workflow examples from others who are doing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Replied at http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?messageID=257366608

Comment: Thanks Matt, I like your suggestions, and will start implementing them!

Comment: That link currently leads to the index page, not the reply. Could you post a summary of your answer here on stackoverflow instead, so we don't depend on external sites?

Answer (score 1):

There are two plugins which look like they do this decently:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.codedoers.jira.repeating-issues/server/overview for Jira Server, and
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.gebsun.atlassian.rtasks/cloud/overview for Jira Cloud.

It's also allegedly possible to use a workflow post-function to create a new task (with scripting), so you might be able to have a task spawn a successor with a later due date on Close, for example. I haven't done it myself or found an example, though.